# Deserializar JSON en C#- Keys traen caracteres no asignables para obtenerlos

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

tengo el siguiente problema en mi programa:

recibo un JSON con la siguiente estructura:

[image: estructura del json]

luego al momento de deserializar el json va bien, tengo los objetos y sus llaves, pero el problema es que las llaves traen el signo "-" por lo tanto no puedo

```
 var listProduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ExpandoObject>>(jResult);

                foreach (dynamic prod in listProduct)
                {
                    int aid = Convert.ToInt32(prod.aid.ToString());
                    string title = prod.title;
                    DateTime sentenceDate = Convert.ToDateTime(prod.property-value_546_iso8601);

                    Suseso mySuseso = new Suseso(.......);
                }
```

acceder por el indice no es posible ya que en el mismo indice no vienen siempre los mismos campos.
y por ejemplo hay una llave que se llama "abstract" y si coloco miJson.abstract, me arroja error porque es prohibido.

necesito poder obtener el valor de :

```
miJson.property-value_546_iso8601;
miJson.abstract;
```

en resumen es ¿como le cambio el nombre a una KEY de mi json deserializado?

desde ya muchas gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La mejor forma de realizarlo sería a través de tu modelo, crearte una clase la cual contenga tus llaves, y asignarles la etiqueta de Json Propery a cada una de las propiedades para indicar como deben de ser asignadas cada una de estas propiedades en relación al JSON que estás tratando de deserializar:

```
public class Videogame
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("release_date")]
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
}
```

En este ejemplo vemos como release_date es la llave de tu json el cual cuando realices la deserializacion se mapeará a la propiedad ReleaseDate y podrás utilizarla en todo tu código sin necesidad de preocuparte de las famosas palabras reservadas

Te adjunto el enlace de NewtonSoft por si quieres conocer más del tema:
https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyName.htm

Comment: gracias, revisare la solución.

Comment: muchas gracias, funcionó muy bien.

Comment: De nada, saludos!